# Play audio stream in browser

Tags: javascript, audio-streaming

I have IP camera that can stream audio data. This audio is in not ordinary audio format like MP3 or WAV and is not playable using player like VLC. Device streams ADPCM chunks each of 544 bytes length. Each audio chunk has 32 bytes header that should be removed. So i working on browser-side Javascript code (i plan to make browser extension) that consumes this stream, removes header, then convert it to playable format like PCM and play it in browser.

Here is my piece of code that succeffully done some work in Firefox:

```
    <script>
        let form = document.forms.audioStreamSettings;
        let inputAudioStreamURL = form.elements.audioStreamURL;
        let inputAudioChunksLimit = form.elements.audioChunksLimit;
        let btnStartStream = form.elements.startStream;
        //Start to play audio when click to the button "Play audio stream:"
        btnStartStream.addEventListener('click', () => {
            let audioStreamURL = inputAudioStreamURL.value;
            let audioChunksLimit = inputAudioChunksLimit.value;
            (async () => {
                let response = await fetch(audioStreamURL);
                const reader = response.body.getReader();
                
                const audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

                let receivedLength = 0; // received that many bytes at the moment
                let pcmStream = new Float32Array();
                let audioDataChunks = new Uint8Array(reader.result); // array of received binary chunks (comprises the body)
                for (let step = 0; step < audioChunksLimit; step++) {
                    const {done, value} = await reader.read();
                    if (done) {
                    break;
                    }
                    let audioChunk = new Uint8Array(value);
                    console.log('Audio chunk:');
                    console.log(audioChunk);

                    //Removing header from every piece of audio data
                    adpcmRawChunk = audioChunk.slice(32,544);
                    console.log('Adpcm raw chunk:');
                    console.log(adpcmRawChunk);

                    //Device streams ADPCM audio, convert every piece to PCM
                    var pcmChunk = decodeAdpcm(adpcmRawChunk);

                    //Merge converted pieces to PCM stream
                    pcmStream = Float32Array.from([...pcmStream,...pcmChunk]);

                    receivedLength += audioChunk.length;
                    console.log(`Received ${receivedLength}`);
                }
                

                console.log("pcmStream:");
                console.log(pcmStream);

                
                    
                // Create an empty buffer at the sample rate of the AudioContext
                const audioBuffer = audioCtx.createBuffer(
                    1,
                    pcmStream.length,
                    8000
                );
                    
                // Fill the buffer with PCM stream data
                for (let channel = 0; channel < audioBuffer.numberOfChannels; channel++) {
                // This gives us the actual array that contains the data
                    const nowBuffering = audioBuffer.getChannelData(channel);
                    for (let i = 0; i < audioBuffer.length; i++) {
                        nowBuffering[i] = pcmStream[i];
                    }
                }

                // Get an AudioBufferSourceNode.
                // This is the AudioNode to use when we want to play an AudioBuffer
                const source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();

                // set the buffer in the AudioBufferSourceNode
                source.buffer = audioBuffer;

                // connect the AudioBufferSourceNode to the
                // destination so we can hear the sound
                source.connect(audioCtx.destination);

                // start the source playing
                source.start();
            })()
        })

    </script>
```

The problem with this code that it is capture specified number of chunks, save it to the memory (array) and then play it.
But i need play audio stream real-time and continously. I also want to have a stop button to stop playing audio stream.

Please give me a right direction to improve this code further and achive what i want.

Comment: How long for a chunk of audio data can be played?

Comment: After get the request device responses with audio chunks infinetly (streaming). I need play audio continously until it is not stoped by "Stop" button.